# Flask Extension not found in Virtual Environment after transfer to new computer

Tags: python, virtualenv, flask

I'll preface this by admitted that I may not totally understand the inner-workings of Virtual Environments, so please forgive me if I've committed an utter fail.

For my Desktop (Mac OS X 10.7 + Python 2.7) I have a Virtual Environment that houses a web application I'm building in Python (using Flask as the framework). I wanted to do some work on laptop, so I zipped up the directory that contained the virtual environment and my code and transfered it over to my laptop (Mac OS X 10.7 + Python 2.7).

After unzipping, I tried to launch my application and received the following message:

```
(venv)****:*** ***$ python runserver.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from weirdcanada import app
  File "/Users/****/****/weirdcanada/weirdcanada/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import weirdcanada.views
  File "/Users/****/****/weirdcanada/weirdcanada/views.py", line 18, in <module>
    from flaskext.principal import AnonymousIdentity
ImportError: No module named flaskext.principal
```

I then tried `pip install flask-principal` and after installing it, I re-ran the application and  received the same error.  I checked the `site-packages` in the virtual environment and `flask-principal` is installed.

My questions:

1. Am I misunderstanding the point of Virtual Environments? Should I be able to copy a Virtual Environment over like I have? I thought consistency and portability were the main features.
2. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that changing this line:

```
    from flaskext.principal
```

to

```
    from flask.ext.principal
```

should work.

I have 3 virtual environments installed on my system(Mac OSX 10.6 + Python2.7). I created a new virtualenv and suddenly the code which is working fine in other virtualenv is not working here and in that case flaskext.wtf was the culprit.

I checked versions of flask and its extensions in both the virtualenvs and they were exactly same so version problem was also out of question.

It does not make sense why this should happen but anyways try this and reply back.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. However, I had to install all the python modules on my laptop (after `sourceing` the virtual environment). I thought a benefit of Virtual Environments was encapsulation, or am I not understanding how the linking works.

Comment: @weirdcanada Purpose of virtualenv is package separation. You should be able to work with different versions of a package in different projects. So every virtualenv need installation of packages again. There is also option of using packages of default installation but that defeats the purpose in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for clarifying the Virtual Environment stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but are you calling the system wide python installation, or the python binary that is in the virtual environment? A virtual environment will obviously have its own python binary interpreter, and all of the packages should be installed using that binary to do the installs. I.e. there should be a system wide python binary at /usr/bin/ or whatever, and another one at /var/www/myapp/env/bin/ or something like that. Thats the one that needs to get the app isntalled with in the virtual environment.

Comment: he does have the (venv) in the prompt, so I'm assuming he sourced bin/activate

Comment: Yes, I've `sourced` into the virtual environment. See my comment above (beneath the first answer).

Comment: (see my commend below, rather)